# How to enable the Create Unit Tests… popup in sql server object explorer Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, unit-testing

I having a problem with unit test for sql in visual studio ultimate 2013. I created SQL Server Database Project to unitest and connect the specific Server (like 10.11.31.1) with 'sa' database. Then I get all Stored, Table, Function... of it. But when I right click in a stored produred in Solution Explorer. there is not had the "Create Unit Tests..." popup. The same for SQL Server Object Explorer (it is disabled). How can I test in this case?
Please help me.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Object Explorer is the place to do this, and if it is disabled, then that indicates that there is an error somewhere in the script of the schema (maybe the stored procedure itself).  When you correct the errors, it will no longer be disabled.

Some things you can try...

1. Try building the project to see if the compiler finds the error.
2. Follow the Walkthrough: Creating and Running a SQL Server Unit Test, found here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851212(v=vs.103).aspx